# DIV Side menu after top div menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

left side menu height not fit to right side div content. I tried left menu for height 100% but even its not work. I need when scroll page whole page should be scroll.

https://syncfiddle.net/fiddle/-Mdpe21LsbBunh7MIwuy

```js
var navList = document.getElementById("nav-lists");

function Show() {
  navList.classList.add("_Menus-show");
}

function Hide() {
  navList.classList.remove("_Menus-show");
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("left").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("right").style.marginLeft = "0";
}

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("left").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("right").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type=button],
input[type=submit],
input[type=reset] {
  background-color: #6e2162;
  border: 1px;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=tel],
input[type=password] {
  width: 340px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  margin: 0px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid deepskyblue;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

select {
  width: 340px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  margin: 0px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid deepskyblue;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.txtform {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.hrform {
  border: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}

.navbar1 {
  width: 99%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar1 a {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #d9099e;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 20%;
  /* Four links of equal widths */
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 3px solid silver;
}

.navbar1 a:hover {
  color: ;
}

.navbar1 a.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d9099e;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
  color: #d9099e;
}


/* NAV BAR END */

.navbar2 {
  width: 99%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar2 a {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 14px;
  color: #5c5c5c;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  /* width: 20%; Four links of equal widths */
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar2 a:hover {
  color: #d9099e;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar2 a.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #6e2162;
}


/* NAV BAR END */

.container {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #6e2162;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .logo {
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .logo a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
}

.container .logo a img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 60px;
}

.container .navbar {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.container .navbar ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container .navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5c5c5c;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.container .navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #d9099e;
  /* background-color: rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.9);  */
}

.container .navbar ul .close {
  display: none;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container .navbar ul .close span {
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #d9099e;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .navbar .icon-bar {
  padding: 18px 8px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .navbar .icon-bar i {
  background-color: #d9099e;
  height: 2px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .container {
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .container .logo {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .container .navbar {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0;
    flex: 0;
  }
  .container .navbar ul {
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    position: fixed;
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-transition: left .3s;
    -o-transition: left .3s;
    transition: left .3s;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .container .navbar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #555555;
  }
  .container .navbar ul .close {
    display: block;
  }
  .container .navbar .icon-bar {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .container .navbar ._Menus-show {
    left: 0;
  }
  .tabadd tr {
    display: grid;
  }
}

.body {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.right {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: silver;
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 15px;
}

.vertical-menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: gray;
  float: left;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  left: 0;
  top: 180px;
}

.vertical-menu a {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color: #f5f5f5;height: 40px;">

  <div class="navbar2">
    <a class="active">&#8250; LOG IN / REGISTER</a>
    <a>&#8250; CONTACT US</a>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="container" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3jar.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/microsoft.png" alt="logo" style="width:120px;height:36px;"></a>
  </div>
  <!--https://www.w3jar.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/microsoft.png -->
  <div class="navbar">

    <div class="icon-bar" onclick="Show()">
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
      <i></i>
    </div>

    <ul id="nav-lists">
      <li class="close"><span onclick="Hide()">×</span></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="background-color: #6e2162;height: 80px;">


</div>

<div class="navbar">

  <div id="right" class="right"><span class="openmenu" style="position:relative;left: 2px; font-size:20px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>

    <div class="body">


      <div class="tabbar">
        <div class="navbar1">
          <a class="active">Register</a>
          <a>Finish</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- NAVBAR END -->

      <div style="height: 30px;"> </div>

      <div class="tabbar"> &nbsp; &nbsp; <b>Student's Information <?php echo $msg; ?> </b>
        <div style="padding:4px; border-top: 0px solid #ddd;" ;> </div>
        <div style="background-color: whitesmoke;padding:10px;border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 5px;">
          <table class="tabadd" border="0">
            <col width='40%'>
            <col width='30%'>
            <col width='10%'>
            <form method="post" action='./step/'>
              <input type='hidden' name='email' /><input type='hidden' name='pass' />
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform">First Name:</td>
                <td class="txtform"> <input type='text' name='fstnm' autofocus required/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform">Last Name:</td>
                <td class="txtform"> <input type='text' name='lstnm' required/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform">Telephone:</td>
                <td class="txtform"> <input type='tel' name='tel' placeholder="Telephone No" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform">Address:</td>
                <td class="txtform"> <input type='text' name='address' required/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform">Gender:</td>
                <td class="txtform">
                  <select name='gender' required/>
                  <option>Male</option>
                  <option>Female</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform">Date of Birth:</td>
                <td class="txtform"> <input type='text' name='DOB' placeholder="Date of Birth" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform">NIC No:</td>
                <td class="txtform"> <input type='text' name='nic' placeholder="optinal" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform">Subject:</td>
                <td class="txtform">
                  <select name='classnm' required/>
                  <option disabled selected></option>
                  <?php echo $options; ?>
                  </select>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform" colspan="2" style="color:gray;text-align:center;">Registration Details</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform" colspan="2">
                  <hr class="hrform"></hr>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform">Reg No.:</td>
                <td class="txtform"> <input type='text' name='regno' placeholder="Admission No." /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform">Reg Date:</td>
                <td class="txtform"> <input type='text' name='regdt' placeholder="Reg. Date (optinal)" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform" colspan="2" style="color:gray;text-align:center;">Teacher Details</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform" colspan="2">
                  <hr class="hrform"></hr>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform">Teacher Name:</td>
                <td class="txtform"> <input type='text' name='mname' placeholder="Teacher Name" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform">Teacher ID:</td>
                <td class="txtform"> <input type='text' name='fname' placeholder="Teacher Trinity ID" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform">Mobile No:</td>
                <td class="txtform"> <input type='tel' name='mtel' placeholder="Teacher Mobile No." /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform">Email ID:</td>
                <td class="txtform"> <input type='tel' name='ftel' placeholder="Teacher Email ID:" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform">School Name:</td>
                <td class="txtform"> <input type='text' name='schnm' placeholder="Teacher School Name" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform">Address:</td>
                <td class="txtform"> <input type='text' name='address' placeholder="Teacher address" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="txtform"> &nbsp; </td>
                <td class="txtform"> <input type='submit' name='register' value='Submit' /></td>
              </tr>
            </form>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- NAVBAR END -->

      <div class="tabbar" style="padding:10px;">

      </div>
      <!-- NAVBAR END -->
    </div>
    <!-- BODY END -->

  </div>

  <div id="left" class="vertical-menu">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">CLOSE &times;</a>
    <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>

  </div>

</div>


<div class="body">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve the effect by adding the following CSS to your stylesheet.

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
}
  
.right {
    height: auto;
}

.vertical-menu {
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Great! Could you please accept the answer? There's a 'check' thing (like a v) next to the answer which you can click on. When it turns green it means you accepted that answer.

Comment: can you please help me how make sub menu under about > menu 1, menu 2